# How to Change a Swing JFrame Size on the fly

Tags: java, swing

What I am trying to achieve is

1. Create a custom component (`mypanel`) that extends `JPanel` with `JLabel`s and `JButton`s in it arranged via `GridBagLayout`.
2. Have a `JFrame` that would display multiple `mypanel` in a vertical stack and have its height change accordingly, depending on the number of `mypanel`s added to it (width of the `JFrame` = width of `mypanel`).
3. When the `JFrame`'s height becomes greater than the screen height, have a vertical scrollbar appear for scrolling

I have created `mypanel` successfully but having lot of trouble with the adding to the `JFrame` and setting its size, scrollbars part.

this is the code for my jframe

```
    this.window = new JFrame("ADesktop Notifications");
    this.window_panel = new JPanel();
    this.window_panel_scroll = new JScrollPane(this.window_panel);

    this.window.setBounds(this.top_left_x,this.top_left_y, this.width, this.height);
    this.window_panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.window_panel.setAutoscrolls(true);
    this.window.add(this.window_panel);
```

Comment: It is a simple enough problem, but including some code snippets of what you are actually working on would help us see the issue your implementation is having.

Answer (score 2):

Try this example out (for dynamic expanding JFrame).

[image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DynaFrame extends JFrame{

    private JPanel basePnl = new JPanel();

    public DynaFrame(){
        this.setTitle("Dynamic panel addition");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //this.setSize(600, 700);
        this.add(getMainPanel());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DynaFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel(){
        basePnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basePnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        basePnl.add(getRowPanel());
        return basePnl;
    }

    public JPanel getRowPanel(){
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gLayout = new GridLayout();
        gLayout.setColumns(4);
        gLayout.setRows(1);
        pnl.setLayout(gLayout);
        pnl.add(new JLabel("Filetype"));
        pnl.add(new JTextField());
        pnl.add(new JButton("Browse"));
        JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
        addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                basePnl.add(getRowPanel());
                DynaFrame.this.pack();
            }
        });
        pnl.add(addBtn);
        return pnl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help ! almost there .. this is what it looks like now http://imgur.com/oaTiW the colored blocks are jpanels that get dynamically added to the main jframe. now how do i make the jframe scrollable ?